# Swift Generic Type conversion?

Tags: swift, generics

I am new to Swift, and I am trying to mess around with the generics a bit, but I am getting strange build errors that I don't understand.  Here is the example code:

```
class CJunk
{
    var HowMuch:Int = 0
}

class CGarbage : CJunk
{

}

// This will not compile because:
// Cannot convert return expression of type 'CGarbage' to return type 'T'
func MakeGarbage<T:CJunk>(input:CJunk) -> T
{
    let x: CGarbage = CGarbage()
    x.HowMuch = input.HowMuch * 2;
    return x;
}
```

OK, that seems odd since CGargabe is a CJunk...  Let's try something a little more basic:

```
// Cannot convert return expression of type 'CJunk' to return type 'T'
func MakeGarbage<T:CJunk>(input:CJunk) -> T
{
    let x: CJunk = CJunk()
    x.HowMuch = input.HowMuch * 2;
    return x;
}
```

**EDIT:**
The problem is that in each case I am erroneously trying to upcast.  This actually has nothing to do with generics, and more with OOP fundamentals.  The other problem is that I misinterpreted the error message.  Ooops.

Comment: `<T:CJunk>` specifies that `T` is an (arbitrary) *subclass* of `CJunk`, that's why you cannot return an instance of CJunk or CGarbage. – What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not about generics in Swift, but about Generics in basically every language. Your code will not work in Java for example either.

Comment: @A.R. the first sample or the second one? The second one might work (not too familiar with C# generics). The first one should not work for the exact reason I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What MartinR already mentioned a bit more clearly stated:

`<T:CJunk>` means that `T` is **one very specific** subclass of `CJunk`. Since you try to return `CGarbage` or `CJunk` there is no guarantee whatsoever that that returned class actually matches the specific `T` - it may not be convertable.

Your example is so simply that generics is simply overkill and the *easy* solution is to drop them altogether since your function returns the same type all the time any way:

```
func MakeGarbage(input:CJunk) -> CGarbage {
    let x: CGarbage = CGarbage()
    x.HowMuch = input.HowMuch * 2;
    return x;
}
```

We will be happy to help with more complex generics problems - this one is so basic that it simply does not make any sense at all to use generics at all.

If you think about your generic Method the compiler has to somehow infer the type `T` or *you* have to specify the type. The compiler cannot infer it in the first place, if you would get over the initial compiler error. Therefore you as the developer would have to provide the type of `T` explicitly. When you do that and specify that `T` has to actually be `YourSecondSubclass` then it is easy to see why the compiler complains in the first place, because now your method will return a `CGarbage` which is clearly not convertable to `YourSecondSubclass`. I hope that explains it a bit!?

Consider the following

```
class CJunk { var HowMuch:Int = 0 }
class CGarbage : CJunk { }
class MoreGarbage : CJunk { }

func MakeGarbage<T:CJunk>(input:CJunk) -> T {
    let x: CGarbage = CGarbage()
    x.HowMuch = input.HowMuch * 2;
    return x;
}

var more : MoreGarbage = MakeGarbage(CJunk())
```

The compiler no goes ahead and infers `T` to be `MoreGarbage` since that is the expected return type, no unfortunately the actual returned type `CGarbage` has nothing to do with `MoreGarbage`.

This argument works for both cases exactly the same: the compiler infers the type of `T` from the caller and there is no guarantee that the you can convert `CJunk` to `T`.

Comment: @A.R. I am not 100% sure about the second base about CJunk -> CJunk, I will include a litte bit more clarification for the first case and to why it is not allowed.

Comment: @A.R. I actually fully understood it now ;) does my example shed a bit more light on it? Or are you still unsure?

Comment: @A.R. NO, it is inferring the exactly correct type... based on the caller, the method body does not matter for the inferring of `T` as it shouldn't. If the body would determine the type, then the type does not need to be generic.

Comment: OK, I was wrong.  The problem is that I am technically trying to upcast in each case, which is why it is bonking out on me.  The unfamiliar language . / error message and (mostly) my frustration blinded me to fact that the code is simply illegal, in any language.  Sorry for being such a pain in the ass about it, I should have been more patient.

Comment: @A.R. No offense taken - note that your "new" question will not compile since you try to init `T` without a `required init`. And now my answer does not match the question any more :/

Comment: I was trying to delete the whole thing because it is kind of a silly question at the end of the day.  I can't do that because there is an answer.  Seriously though, when the error message said can't convert 'CType to CType' that just confused the shit out of me and I went down the wrong path. :)

Comment: @A.R. I do understand that but still think that question was quite valid - me personally I would revert the edit to the original question and move on, maybe a new user will stumble upon it and will understand what is going wrong for him

Comment: OK, it's back with an explanation about what the real problem is (the guy at the keyboard :))